# DicomImage's writeBMP function produces unclear gray image

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I am using DCMTK to read and hopefully modify DICOM images. I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <dcmtk\dcmimgle\dcmimage.h>

int main() {
    try {
        DicomImage* dicomImage = new DicomImage("C:/Users/Kriselle/Documents/000004.dcm");
        if ((dicomImage != NULL) && (dicomImage->isMonochrome())) {
            dicomImage->writeBMP("C:/Users/Kriselle/Documents/z.bmp", 8);
            std::cout << "z.bmp is created" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "dicomImage is null or not monochrome" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (cv::Exception e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

All I did was create a DicomImage and write its pixel data to a BMP file with the filename I specified but the image returns only a gray image with the outline of the original image barely recognized.

This is what it should look like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6dw8nlae8hfvqf6/000004.jpg?dl=0
This is what the code produces: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fff2kch124bzjqy/z.bmp?dl=0

Am I missing something in the code or did I not understand what the function does? Can anyone please enlighten me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the API documentation of the [DicomImage](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/classDicomImage.html) class, the default is that no VOI transformation is enabled when rendering monochrome DICOM images. In your case, this seems to be inappropriate, so you should specify a more appropriate VOI setting (e.g. a [min-max window](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/classDicomImage.html#a8600a76ba5ba76bda729704098464f87)) or use one of the [VOI windows stored in the DICOM dataset](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/classDicomImage.html#aa436e4e9c2841bc26c737b26dedfc099) (if any).

By the way, after loading the image in the constructor, you should also check the status of this process using the getStatus() method.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! That did the trick! I'll have to read more on VOI transformation to understand how it worked.